# html comment box cutting text without going onto new line

Tags: html, css

[image]

when i insert a comment more than the set width (600px) the text will just cut off (see image link above) instead of going onto a new line. I am using html comment box. 
the style for the comment box is:

```
 #HCB_comment_box div.comment {
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
  width: 600px;

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the word-wrap property

```
#HCB_comment_box div.comment {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3y2Q/)

Comment: @lukey, Updated :), Demo as well.

Comment: thanks worked do you know how to get rid of the blue line to the left of comment?

Comment: @lukey, it is probably a border, use `border-left: none;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#HCB_comment_box div.comment {
word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior. You've inserted a VERY log word and it IS one word... What would you expect? ) If you insert a couple of spaces there it will help)

Comment: does not make a different if there are spaces

Comment: I'd say then you need to give us a jsfiddle or online example... probably there is a `white-space: nowrap` property is there with `overflow: hidden` cuts off your comment...

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can define in your css properties

Use the word-wrap

```
#HCB_comment_box div.comment {
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
  width: 600px;
word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

using word-wrap:break-word ,because The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

see the result: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap